# Any suggestion for using non-blocking MySQL api on Tornado in Python3?

Tags: python, database, asynchronous, io, tornado

i was hoping tornado support for asynchronous sql database opertion ,after i read the source code,

http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/database.html#Connection

sigh,they are blocking version.here's some choice .

Plan A: find a set of api similar to mysqldb module except they use callback to return the reuslt.sorry i didn't find one that show examples that's their api can handle non-blocking mysql operation

Plan B: use the  block version .i heard the writer of tornado suggest developers use block version,and extremely optimize your sql query for shorten the blocking period.

in my case: the server need to handle receive 2k request per second in peak hour and most of them need query and update from database ,suggest every operation take 10ms,10ms*2k over 20s ,that would be a nightmare.in multi thread programming at least i can make more connections for more average response time.

maybe i missed some point here,i have not much experience for backend development.however i still think using blocking io api is a suck idea while the framework is non-blocking.

Plan C: drop MySql use mongoDB, i heard mongoDB has an asynchronous Python implement api named asyncmongo, but im not sure the risk to learn mongoDB and take mongoDB as our business choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to setup Multiprocessing ( http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing ) and use on of the processes as a Queue manager for the DB.

Combine Multiprocessing with efficient SQL queries and you should minimize your overall impact. The blocking calls will only be done on the DB Processing Queue Manager process and the rest of the application can run without being blocked. The only people affected are the ones attempting to run a DB query at the same time.

Comment: thank you for your answer,is there something already exist i can use it directly or i need to write it by myself? and i don't know the meaning of your last sentence ,you mean in this solution DB query can only be executed one by one,if someone use sql client to query mysql ,then they will fail?

Comment: All Python modules for accessing MySQL at this time, that I am aware of, are blocking calls. To my knowledge there is no way around this. I have seen modifications to the mysqldb module that minimize the blocking calls. But the fact remains that there is no way around it with some MySQL calls. What happens with them is that they queue up. So that when three people attempt to do a MySQL query at once, they are executed in the order they are put into the queue.

Comment: i see ,but i have zero experience at multiprocessing programming,in your describe ,seems like i'll have another process to hold and queue all db queries from my main process and here's the question:can i send  the callback function to the other process?

Comment: There are several ways of implementing it, and many of them do have support for callbacks. http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html