# How to store real-time chat messages in database?

Tags: python, chat, real-time, tornado, mysql-python

I am using `mysqldb` for my database currently, and I need to integrate a messaging feature that is in real-time. The `chat demo` that Tornado provides *does not* implement a database, (whereas the `blog` *does*.)

This messaging service also will also double as an email in the future (like how Facebook's message service works. The chat platform is also email.) Regardless, I would like to make sure that my current, first chat version will be able to be expanded to function as email, and overall, I need to store messages in a database.

Is something like this as simple as: for every chat message sent, query the database and display the message on the users' screen. Or, is this method prone to suffer from high server load and poor optimization? How exactly should I structure the "infrastructure" to make this work?

(I apologize for some of the inherent subjectivity in this question; however, I prefer to "measure twice, code once.")

Input, examples, and resources appreciated. 
Regards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tornado is a single threaded non blocking server.

What this means is that if you make any blocking calls on the main thread you will eventually kill performance. You might not notice this at first because each database call might only block for 20ms. But once you are making more than 200 database calls per seconds your application will effectively be locked up.

However that's quite a few DB calls. In your case that would be 200 people hitting send on their chat message in the same second.

What you probably want to do is use a queue with a non blocking API. So Tornado receives a chat message. You put it on the queue to be saved to the database by another process, then you send the chat message back out to the other chat members.

When someone connects to a chat session you also need to send off a request to the queue for all the previous messages, when the queue responds you send those off to the newly connected user.

That's how I would approach the problem anyway.

Also see this question and answer: [Any suggestion for using non-blocking MySQL api on Tornado in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234998/any-suggestion-for-using-non-blocking-mysql-api-on-tornado-in-python3)

Just remember, Tornado is single threaded. It's amazing. And can handle thousands of simultaneous connections. But if code in one of those connections blocks for 1 second then **NOTHING** else will be done for any other connection during that second.

Comment: Wow this is a great answer, thank you for your help on this. This makes perfect sense and is a great place to start.

Comment: Can you tell that I've used blocking calls on the Tornado loop in a production app before? :)