# How do I cleanly exit from a multiprocessing script?

Tags: python, real-time, multiprocessing, nonblocking

I am building a non-blocking chat application for my website, and I decided to implement some multiprocessing to deal with DB querying and real-time messaging.

I assume that when a user lands on a given URL to see their conversation with the other person, I will fire off the script, the multiprocessing will begin, the messages will be added to a queue and displayed on the page, new messages will be sent to a separate queue that interacts with the DB, etc. (Regular message features ensue.)

However, what happens when the user leaves this page? I assume I need to exit these various processes, but currently, this does not lend itself to a "clean" exit. I would have to terminate processes and according to the multiprocessing docs:

```
Warning: If this method (terminate()) is used when the associated process is using a pipe 
or queue then the pipe or queue is liable to become corrupted and may become 
unusable by other process.Similarly, if the process has acquired a lock or 
semaphore etc. then terminating it is liable to cause other processes to 
deadlock.
```

I have also looked into `sys.exit()`; however, it doesn't fully exit the script without the use of `terminate()` on the various processes.

Here is my code that is simplified for the purposes of this question. If I need to change it, that's completely fine. I simply want to make sure I am going about this appropriately.

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import time
import sys

## Get all past messages
def batch_messages():   

    # The messages list here will be attained via a db query
    messages = [">> This is the message.", ">> Hello, how are you doing today?", ">> Really good!"]
    for m in messages:
        print m

## Add messages to the DB   
def add_messages(q2):   

    while True:
        # Retrieve from the queue
        message_to_db = q2.get()

        # For testing purposes only; perfrom another DB query to add the message to the DB
        print message_to_db, "(Add to DB)"

## Recieve new, inputted messages.
def receive_new_message(q1, q2):

    while True:
        # Add the new message to the queue:
        new_message = q1.get()

        # Print the message to the (other user's) screen
        print ">>", new_message

        # Add the q1 message to q2 for databse manipulation
        q2.put(new_message)

def shutdown():
    print "Shutdown initiated"
    p_rec.terminate()
    p_batch.terminate()
    p_add.terminate()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set up the queue
    q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Set up the processes
    p_batch = multiprocessing.Process(target=batch_messages)
    p_add = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_messages, args=(q2,))
    p_rec = multiprocessing.Process(target=receive_new_message, args=(q1, q2,))

    # Start the processes   
    p_batch.start() # Perfrom batch get 
    p_rec.start()
    p_add.start()

    time.sleep(0.1) # Test: Sleep to allow proper formatting

    while True:

        # Enter a new message
        input_message = raw_input("Type a message: ")

        # TEST PURPOSES ONLY: shutdown
        if input_message == "shutdown_now":
            shutdown()

        # Add the new message to the queue:
        q1.put(input_message)

        # Let the processes catch up before printing "Type a message: " again. (Shell purposes only)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

How should I deal with this situation? Does my code need to be fundamentally revised?, and if so, what should I do to fix it?

Any thoughts, comments, revisions, or resources appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: N.B: You don't need to prefix your titles with "python – ", that's what StackOverflow's tags are for.

Comment: Valid point and now fixed.

Comment: So why can't you do a clean exit? On shutdown pass message to each subprocess that it should stop doing whatever it's doing and quit. You will probably need a seperate thread (on each subprocess) for that.

Comment: Oh, BTW: can't you use threads instead of processes? It is safer and easier to maintain.

Comment: What's the problem with terminate? I guess it should work fine.

Comment: @freakish: I decided to give the multiprocessing a go after reading about it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442265/how-to-store-real-time-chat-messages-in-database for more info. However, I am interested in hearing of a better way to do this using single threads. Do you know of any resources that I might be able to learn from in this case?

Comment: @JohnZ I'm not saying single thread. Exactly the same can be achieved with *multiple* threads. Try using `threading` module.

Comment: Alrighty, simple as that. I'll take a look; thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't actually know python.  But multithreadding concepts are similar enough in all the langauges I do know that I feel confident enough to try to answer anyway.*

When using multiple threads/proccesses each one should have a step in it's loop to check a variable, (I often call the variable "active", or "keepGoing" or something and it's usually a boolean.)

That variable is usually either shared between the threads, or sent as a message to each thread depending on your programming language and when you want the proccessing to stop, (finish your work first y/n?)

Once the variable is set all threads quit their proccessing loops and proceed to exit their threads.

In your case you have a loop "while true". This never exits.  Change it to exit when a variable is set and the thread should close itself when the function exit is reached.

Comment: Thanks for your input on the matter. I will definitely test is out.